# Regular expression for Notepad++ to replace this?

Tags: regex, notepad++

This is an example of what I want to replace

```
3</td><td width="8%">2
```

with

```
3 and 2
```

**But** the regex should match any number before the  like the 3 above for the example, and the number 2 is always number 2

if you find a number before `</td><td width="8%">` and the number 2 after it, you keep the numbers and replace `</td><td width="8%">` with the word `and`

Thank you

Comment: Um... can't you just replace `</td><td width="8%">` with `and` without using a regex? Just a standard replace?

Comment: always ends with 2? `</td><td width="8%">2` -> `and 2`. And yeah, as Kolink said: no regex.

Comment: @Kolink No I can't, it will replace it also from places I dont want to.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to match with the following regex:

```
([0-9]+)</td><td\s*width="8%">2
```

and replace with the following:

```
$1 and 2
```

Look at the picture below:

[image: Regex]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

`[0-9]+</td><td\swidth="8%">2`

If you editor supports groupped editing, use paranthesis to mark each group then edit the one you need.

Groupped version:

`([0-9]+)(</td><td\swidth="8%">)(2)`

Comment: Thank you for this but I loose all the numbers before the `</td>`

Comment: @Kaoukkos: replace with "`\1 and 2`"

Comment: The parentheses around the HTML tags are unnecessary. Remove them (regex becomes `(\d+)</td><td width="8%">2`) and replace with `\1 and 2`

Answer (score 0):

Capture the preceding number and output it back out in the replacement text using a back reference:

Search:

```
(\d+)</td><td width="8%">2
```

Replace:

```
\1 and 2
```